# Open slide menu navigation from right to left in iOS

Tags: ios

I have an slider menu in my iOS project which opens by default from left to right. I wanted to ask how can I make it open from right to left. There are many android topics on this but I didn't find any iOS tips for doing this.
Thanks very much

Comment: Can you give us more details please? Are you using a specific library for your slider? Is it your own code? If so, can you show us the relevant lines? Thanks!

Comment: No , just standard slider , I just wanna know if you guys have any idea on how to make it to the right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using AMSlideMenu (https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/AMSlideMenu), you need to drag a segue between the **main view** and your **right menu view**, and you choose **slide menu right menu**, then implement the method **segueIdentifierForIndexPathInRightMenu**. The segue takes care that the menu will open, and the **rightmenu** option assures the menu will open from right to left. Next video explains it all :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y33t_bWS_Zk